# Extract audio data from a bagfile into mp3 or wav format

Tags: ros, audio-common, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS Community,

I am a beginner to ROS. I used the audio_capture package provided by ROS Wiki to capture the audio data from a usb-microphone and use rosbag record to record the audio topic into a bagfile. Using the audio_play package provided, I was able to hear the audio when I rosbag play the bagfile. Now I want to extract the audio data of the bagfile to a external mp3 or wav file, but I don't know how to.

I know that the audio_capture package does contain a capture_to_file.launch file to capture real-time audio into mp3 file, but I only want the historical audio data recorded by the bagfile.

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281340/extract-audio-data-from-a-bagfile-into-mp3-or-wav-format/) by [Teddy_NTU](https://answers.ros.org/users/33489/teddy_ntu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't used it myself, but [sbrodeur/ros-audio-convert](https://github.com/sbrodeur/ros-audio-convert) claims to do just that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Teddy_NTU](https://answers.ros.org/users/33489/teddy_ntu/) on 2018-01-31**:
That works!!! Thanks!!!